# OneSignal - How to send automated, daily messages with updated content each day

Tags: ios, push-notification, onesignal

What I want is to send an automated push notification to users once a day, and have found a way to do this with automated notifications with OneSignal. The problem is that it asks for a title/message to input on their console, but what I wanted was to have a backend (haven't chosen yet, probably Firebase) with some strings, and each day a string will be randomly chosen and that will be automatically pushed to all of my users. Is there a way to do this with OneSignal, and if not with some other push notification service?

Can I accomplish this with the OneSignal API, or should I write some custom script and host it somewhere (like cron) that sends these using API calls?

thanks